DeviceMotion.isAvailableAsync() return false on Android 13
The code
import { DeviceMotion } from 'expo-sensors'

const devMotionPerm = await DeviceMotion.getPermissionsAsync()
const available = await DeviceMotion.isAvailableAsync()
console.info( 'DeviceMotion sub', devMotionPerm, available )

runs well on Android 10 or 11 and outputs:
INFO  DeviceMotion sub {"canAskAgain": true, "expires": "never", "granted": true, "status": "granted"} true

On Android 13 though the output looks like:
INFO  DeviceMotion sub {"canAskAgain": true, "expires": "never", "granted": true, "status": "granted"} false

So getPermissionsAsync() works fine, whereas isAvailableAsync() fails on Android 13.
These are my essential dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "51.0.24",
    "expo-location": "17.0.1",
    "expo-sensors": "13.0.9",
    "expo-updates": "0.25.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
  }

How to fix it?
What am I missing?
